# SQL group inner join cannot get all results

Tags: php, sql

I really trying to get this SQL to work. Im no expert so really cant figure this out.

```
$sqlquery = " SELECT 
    s.searchword AS searchword, 
    s.id AS id, 
    COUNT( c.id ) AS searchresult, 
    s.region AS region 
    FROM search_words AS s 
    INNER JOIN company_data AS c ON 
    c.branch_text LIKE CONCAT(  '%', s.searchword,  '%' )       
    GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY s.date DESC";
```

This gives me:

```
Array
    (
[0] => Array
    (
        [searchword] => WHOLESALE
        [searchid] => 427
        [searchresult] => 98
        [region] => stockholm
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [searchword] => cars
        [searchid] => 426
        [searchresult] => 26
        [region] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [searchword] => Retail
        [searchid] => 342
        [searchresult] => 41
        [region] => stockholm
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [searchword] => Springs
        [searchid] => 339
        [searchresult] => 4
        [region] => stockholm
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [searchword] => Leasing
        [searchid] => 343
        [searchresult] => 2
        [region] => stockholm
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [searchword] => Food
        [searchid] => 340
        [searchresult] => 37
        [region] => stockholm
    )

 )
```

But, it does not give me any of the other results where there are no searchhits, would retur something like [searchresult] => 0. Meaning they do not group as I wish, because there are no such searchwords within the company_data table.

How can I fix this, please help :(

EDIT:

Here is the full code:

```
public function getUserSearches()
    {

    $sqlquery = " SELECT 
    s.searchword AS searchword, 
    s.id AS id, 
    s.userId AS userid, 
    COUNT( c.id ) AS searchresult, 
    s.region AS region 
    FROM search_words AS s 
    INNER JOIN company_data AS c ON 
    c.branch_text LIKE CONCAT(  '%', s.searchword,  '%' )       
    GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY s.date DESC";

     // IS THERE ANYTHING WRONG HERE?? LIKE IT DOES NOT MATCH AGAINST THE USER?
    $result = $this->dbh->query($sqlquery, array(":userId" => $this->user_id));

    $arr = array();
    foreach ($result as $item)  {
        array_push($arr, array('searchword' => $item['searchword'], 'searchid' => $item['id'], 
    'searchresult' => $item['searchresult'], 'userid' => $item['userid'],
    'region' => $item['region']));
    }

    return json_encode($arr);
    return print_r($arr);
}
```

Comment: you can use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. Tell me if that solves your problem or not.

Comment: Almost :) it gave me more results almost all of them 32 och 36, strange. And it did not check for user_id either. This is how I get the result, adding user_id: $result = $this->dbh->query($sqlquery, array(":userId" => $this->user_id)); Perhaps its totaly wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your comment properly. can you please post your php code if you're still facing some problem?

Comment: Yes have a look now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about why you have added `array(":userId" => $this->user_id)` because the parameter expected there is database link. If you want to match against the userid then you can modify your query to include where clause for userid and add a parameter afterwards substituting the userid. in the `query` function call, It does not make any sense.

Comment: It uses a PDO class for database actions. But i'm not that good understanding it, so perhaps it does not match for user through it... I will try to get it going with a where clause.

Comment: Yes! I added a where claus and it worked with the help of another person here.

Comment: cheers! :) And also check the answer that I've posted. Is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` so that any row that doesn't match the search criteria in the join condition will come with null, therefore `count` will be 0. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  s.searchword AS searchword, 
  s.id AS id, 
  s.region AS region,
  COUNT(COALESCE(c.id, 0)) AS searchresult
FROM search_words AS s 
LEFT JOIN company_data AS c 
        ON c.branch_text LIKE CONCAT(  '%', s.searchword,  '%' )       
GROUP BY s.searchword, s.id, s.region
ORDER BY s.date DESC;
```

See [this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for more details about the SQL Join types.

Comment: Thanks, but this one didnt work. I get all results, but I do get [searchresult] => 0.

Comment: @AdrianMcCool - Can you please post some sample records from the two tables `search_words` and `company_data` to know where is the problem?

Comment: I edited post above, including the whole function, perhaps its easier.

Comment: @AdrianMcCool Thaks, but I need some sample records to run the query and see why it is not working, just 3 or 4 records from each table as a sample.

Comment: Well, I cannot give you the company_data table, its to much in there. It just checks the branch_text column for matches. The search_words table just holds id, userId, searchword, date, region

Comment: Your code works! Thank you so much, the problem why it didnt work was the check against user_id wish was totally wrong. I added it to the query and not it runs correctly. Many thanks for this!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need a `LEFT JOIN`, instead of an `INNER JOIN`.  However, there are other simplifications you can make as well:

```
SELECT s.searchword, s.id, COUNT( c.id ) AS searchresult, s.region 
FROM search_words s INNER JOIN
     company_data c
     ON c.branch_text LIKE CONCAT('%', s.searchword, '%')       
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY s.date DESC
```

For instance, you don't need column aliases when you are not changing the column name.  You are only aggregating on `searchword`; I assume this is unique in `search_words`.  Otherwise, `s.id`, `s.region`. and `s.date` would have indeterminate values.

The use of `LIKE` for the `JOIN` affects performance.  If you only have a small amount of data, this is fine.  Otherwise, you might want to think about other data structures.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is perhaps this:

```
public function getUserSearches()
{

$sqlquery = " SELECT 
s.searchword AS searchword, 
s.id AS id, 
s.userId AS userid, 
COUNT( c.id ) AS searchresult, 
s.region AS region 
FROM search_words AS s
WHERE s.userId='"+$this->userid+"'  
LEFT JOIN company_data AS c ON 
c.branch_text LIKE CONCAT(  '%', s.searchword,  '%' )       
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY s.date DESC";

 // IS THERE ANYTHING WRONG HERE?? LIKE IT DOES NOT MATCH AGAINST THE USER?
$result = $this->dbh->query($sqlquery);

$arr = array();
foreach ($result as $item)  {
    array_push($arr, array('searchword' => $item['searchword'], 'searchid' => $item['id'], 
'searchresult' => $item['searchresult'], 'userid' => $item['userid'],
'region' => $item['region']));
}

    return json_encode($arr);
return print_r($arr);
}
```